# Why did the Drakh emissary look so blurred in S04:E11 "Lines of Communication"?

Tags: babylon-5

One thing that has always confused me was why did the Drakh emissary look so blurred in that episode?
Was it any type of cloaking device?

Comment: I have always interpreted it as a cloaking device of a kind, but I may be mistaken.

Comment: @Klaus Æ. Mogensen: I think so too; but if it really is a cloacking device, it is a very lousy one. I would like if there is a canon confirmation of any type.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to [this post](http://www.b5tv.com/showpost.php?s=ae07d33a6eae622aee09fbdb1a7465f3&p=331324&postcount=8) on the B5TV forums, JMS had the following explanation:

> The Drakh emissary is described in the script as a servant of darkness, who causes lights to dim as it nears them as if sucking the life and light out of everything it passes. In the episode, an effect was added in postproduction that turned it into a blurred, indistinct figure. "I had everything darken when he comes near it because I was so burned with the 'Infection' situation and the 'Grey 17' thing," explains Joe Straczynski. "I said, 'I don't want to do another obvious guy in a rubber suit so let's keep this dark and shadowy.' Of course, it was shot nice and bright, and also the paint job on the actual face wasn't what I wanted it to be--it was the wrong color, and it ended up looking like a mask, instead of looking like a breather unit. I thought, 'well, look, these guys worked for the Shadows, they would have some access to Shadow technology, and we know the Shadows can phase in and out of appearance. Why can we not make the logical extension that they have adapted a system which keeps them blurry a little bit?' They really can't be seen clearly and thus, become more ominous and, thus, more frightening to the average passerby."

So, in the original script, there was no blurring effect, only the dimming of lights and so forth. However due to problems with the makeup and other effects, they elected to throw the blurring effect in to help sell the Drakh as a mysterious and alien threat. JMS's post-hoc explanation was that the Drakh were using a Shadow device of some kind, possibly for intimidation purposes (since it doesn't seem to hide them very effectively).

For what it's worth, none of the other episodes that featured Drakh had a similar effect in either B5 or its spinoff *Crusade*, and it was never conclusively demonstrated that they were even the same species as the "emissary" seen in "Lines of Communciation".

Comment: n.b.: "Infection" and "Grey 17 is Missing" were earlier (first- and third-season, respectively) episodes that had been panned for bad creature effects, hence why they felt the Drakh needed to be more impressive.

Comment: Ok. So the explanation is two fold: In universe, as we already suspected, it is a cloaking device. In reality, it is a way to hide the lacks in the creature effects. About being other species, hasnt the Drakhs have two shapes?

Comment: There were two distinct versions of the makeup, [one](https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/babylon5/images/e/e7/Drakh_Emmisary.png/revision/latest?cb=20100601113021) from "Lines of Communication" and [the other](https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/babylon5/images/f/f6/Shiv%27kala.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20080628044058) from "The Fall of Centauri Prime" et al.

Comment: I used to hang out in the B5 usenet newsgroup (both pre and post moderation) during the show's run, and JMS was definitely a master of the post-hoc explanation. I remember he totally sold the captain change as a sad necessity of the story to keep the character from becoming a "Mary Sue", when in reality the actor in question had to leave the show [due to mental health issues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_O%27Hare#Illness_and_death).

Comment: I really wish they kept the blur effect when they brought the Drakh back -- it added a level of surreality to them.